# Disable print, print screen, right click using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to Disable print, print screen, right click using asp.net

Answer (score 3):

You **cant**. You cannot avoid content being copied from your pages.
Disabling Right Click is possible, but it doesnt solve your 'problem'. The user could still copy your image, by disabling javascript or just inspecting the source.

And even if you could disable those keys, the user could still just make a photo of his monitor. Good luck disabling that!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You don't. You are writing a web application; features of the underlying platform are outside your scope, and you have no business trying to fiddle with them.

Long answer: You can try to capture those keys using javascript, and override the default behaviour, which will somewhat stop very naïve users, but all it takes to disable this "security" is to turn off javascript. Even if you come up with more sophisticated "protection", the essence remains: You are sending content to the client, and once it gets there, it is out of your hands. Given suitable tools (wget is enough for most things), anyone can copy and modify your content in any way they like. Similarly, whatever can be shown on the screen inside a browser can be captured and saved. There is no way around it. If you don't want your content copied, don't send it.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about it. You will irritate your end users who will find a way to con you and do what you didn't want them to do. Forbidden fruit is always the sweetest. By telling them explicitly "you cannot do this", they will wonder why do you want to guard your content and they might try even harder to do stuff you otherwise wouldn't want them to do.

Psychology and technology are against you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Printing**

You could disable printing (well sort of - it's not 100% effective) using a "print" style sheet.

I have not tried it myself, but here is a link that could get you started: http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/qt/block_print.htm

**Print screen**

Print screen is something that is typically controlled by the operating system not the browser nor webpage. So you are unlikely to be able to stop this. However, casting my mind back I remember a time (perhaps a long long time ago), where you couldn't take screen shots in Windows (maybe Windows 98) of videos... so if your really in need of disabling print screen - perhaps you could perhaps encode your content in a video... but this will have many many downfalls - namely accessibility, search engine optimisation and it being a royal pain to do... so I wouldn't recommend it under any circumstance.

**Right screen**

Right click you can disable, but not using a server-side technology (such as ASP.net) instead in a client-side technology such as javascript. A quick search in your favourite search engine will find some help. But disabling right click is rudimentary to get around, so it is not full proof.

An alternative to protect your content is to possibly investigate "rights" in PDFs. I believe you can disable the "right" to print.

However none of these solutions are going to be full-proof. As long as you are making your content available to an end-user on their own computer, there is always going to be a way around your restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented for disabling printing using [window.onbeforeprint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeprint_event)
Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72275635/1053191)