# How to trigger javascript on print event?

Tags: javascript, browser, printing

Is it possible to trigger a javascript event when a user prints a page?
I would like to remove a dependancy on a javascript library, when a user opts to print a page, as the library is great for screen but not for print.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "the library is great for screen but not for print"?

Comment: What does a JavaScript library have to do with printing?  The browser doesn't invoke any page scripts when printing anyway.

Comment: use window.onprint function,window.onafterprint,window.onbeforeprint

Comment: impress.js is the library.  As I say looks great on screen but renders to print looking awful

Comment: Supportive information : http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/ where TJ VanToll on Jun 15th, 2012 commented more deeply the situation with onbeforeprint .. etc.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For anyone stumbling upon this answer from Google, let me try to clear things up:

As Ajay pointed out, there are two events which are fired for printing, but they are not well-supported; as far as I have read, they are only supported in Internet Explorer and Firefox (6+) browsers. Those events are window.onbeforeprint and window.onafterprint, which (as you'd expect) will fire before and after the print job.

However, as pointed out in Joe's link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920784/578667), that's not exactly how it is implemented in all cases. In most cases, both events fire before the dialog; in others, script execution might be halted during the print dialog, so both events may fire at the same time (after the dialog has been completed).

For more information (and browser support) for these two events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeprint

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onafterprint

The short answer: if you're hoping to interfere with the print flow, don't. If you're hoping to trigger code after printing, it's not going to work how you're wanting; expect poor browser support, and try to degrade gracefully.

Comment: Additionally, if you are trying to alter the layout or display for print, you should be doing this with a print stylesheet (or `@media print` rules within your css) and not JavaScript

Comment: @TomPietrosanti I totally agree, but there are some things you cannot do with CSS (such as change the order of elements). See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030208/dom-manipulation-on-print-only).

Comment: You can change the order (to a degree) if you can use flexbox, but otherwise that's true.  If you don't need JS, I would avoid it - it can lead so some very strange bugs.

Comment: @TomPietrosanti Flexboxes change the *appearance* of the order, however the DOM tree stays the same. Incidentally, I do want to keep the DOM the same while changing the appearance, so a flexbox seems to be the solution, and a far better one than using JS.

Comment: Good point!  I can definitely see that there may be times when you want the DOM order to change, not just the appearance.

Comment: Compatibility is something to keep in mind if you're going the flexbox route. If your users end up trying to print from a browser that doesn't support that feature, make sure it still looks acceptable for them. If you're using a feature detection library (like Modernizr), you should be able to check for parent classes like .flexbox (or .flexbox-legacy if you want to fall back on that syntax), and provide alternate styles for .no-flexbox for users who don't have all that fancy bling in their browsers.

Comment: Since Chrome 63, Chrome now supports `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onbeforeprint`.

Comment: Has the answer changed at all now that it's 2021?

Answer (score 15):

It can be done by overwriting, e.g., `window.onbeforeprint`.

Using Chrome, I found that the more arcane `window.matchMedia("print").addListener(function() {alert("Print Dialog open.")})` also works.

This debatable feature can be used in order to deter users from printing a page.

I've encountered it the first time on [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/125450990/e-WATCH-INC-v-AVIGILON-CORPORATION). There, if you open the print dialog using the menu command, the page content will be greyed out and a warning pop-over message appears explaining why you can not print the page. (Note for complete analysis: on that page, control-p is also overriden so you can not use it to open the print dialog at all. Additionally, there is a @media CSS for printer output that hides the content; all tested on Firefox).

Comment: In Chrome, your "arcane" solution does work, but it happens four times.

Comment: I imagine if you have multiple print styles or print stylesheets it would fire for as many as you have. When I run this code with no print styles it runs once.

Comment: Since Chrome 63, Chrome now supports `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onbeforeprint`.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented for disabling printing using [window.onbeforeprint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeprint_event)

```
/*Block printing*/    
    window.onbeforeprint = (event) => {
        console.log("onbeforeprint function");
        printDiabled();
    };

    function printDiabled() {
        var headstr = " <span style='font-size: large; font - weight: bold; color: Red''>PRINT IS DISABLED</span>";

        //var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = headstr;
    }
    /*Block printing*/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a scenario where u want to do something before print dialog appears or just after the document is sent to printer queue use can use the below events
window.onafterprint , window.onbeforeprint

Comment: I tried in Chome, but it doesn't work. Although it might in IE, but IE is no good to me here. Thanks.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9920784/578667

Comment: With a bit a hackerydoo, you can get it to work in webkit based browsers too:  http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/  The only one left out is Opera, but an enterprising individual could probably come up with a polyfill/hack for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here looking for an option using Bootstrap as I was, I used the following code to achieve this **when a print button is clicked**. This **won't** work when they press CTRL + P.

```
$("#print_page").click(function(){
$("#print_section").addClass('visible-print-block');
window.print();
$("#print_section").removeClass('visible-print-block');})
```

You need to add hidden-print to anything you don't want printed and then add an ID (or a class if you have more than one section) of print_section to the bit you want printed! Bit hacky but it works!

Comment: You can also [override CTRL + P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680946/479156) to fire the same code/function, but that still is not 100% proof since there are more ways to print.