# DOM manipulation on print only

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to do

```
$('#foo').insertAfter('#bar');
```

but **only when the user prints the page**. I don't want to do any scripting while on screen.

I realize this would have been simple if I wanted to manipulate styles, because then I would have just used `@media print {}` in CSS. However the goal I am trying to achieve (DOM manipulation) cannot be achieved with CSS, hence I need to use JS.

How can I run JavaScript (or jQuery) **only** when the user prints or does print-preview?

Comment: Related: [detecting-browser-print-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234008/detecting-browser-print-event)

Comment: Surely you could actually insert `foo` after `bar` before and have it only set to `display` in the CSS for `print`?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I'm not sure if I understand your question. Before printing, (on screen), `#foo` appears before `#bar`. When printing, I want to reorder the elements such that `#foo` displays after `#bar` rather than before (as on screen and in the source code).

Comment: oh right, so `#foo` is already on the page at that point.  In which case perhaps look into this http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/

Comment: related: [How to trigger javascript on print event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138939/how-to-trigger-javascript-on-print-event)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about cross browser functionality you can use the [window.onbeforeprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeprint) event, but it is only supported in IE and firefox 6+

```
window.onbeforeprint = function(){
     $('#foo').insertAfter('#bar');
};
```

Another way is to override the CTRL+P keystrokes

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  var char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);  
  if(char == "P" && e.ctrlKey){
      $('#foo').insertAfter('#bar');
  }
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pevans02/38fZG/)

But this will not work if the user uses the menu system to do a print or right clicks to print.

Comment: Your second solution also won't work on a Mac when the "control" key is really a "command" key.

Comment: well obviously change the keys to the correct ones for the system