Add Page Numbers to a Printed HTML Page Using CSS Only
I am trying to print a dynamically generated HTML, and wish to have a page number included on each page.
I have read a number of previous questions on a similar topic but all seem to be way out of date.
My question is the following CSS supported anymore?
#pageFooter:after {
counter-increment: page;
content: counter(page); }

If it is how should it be correctly defined?
If not, what are the alternatives?
Thanks

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter

Can't you just try it and see if it works?

@j08691 I have tried loads times, from various sources, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Hence my question.

@admcfajn It doesn't mention in "page" can be countered however.

What does your html look like? Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050939/print-page-numbers-on-pages-when-printing-html the counter css referss to the index of a list and can be used to skip numbers, reset the index, that kind of thing... You could wrap each page in a list-item, or build the pages into your html markup. JavaScript would probably help out a lot here, you might need to run it when the page is printed, so this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138939/how-to-trigger-javascript-on-print-event
